# Spring autowire byName not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Spring autowire byName not working as expected.

```
public class SpellChecker {
    public SpellChecker() {
        System.out.println("Inside SpellChecker constructor." );
    }

    public void checkSpelling() {
        System.out.println("Inside checkSpelling." );
    }
}

public class TextEditor {

       private SpellChecker spellChecker1;
       private String name;

       public void setSpellChecker( SpellChecker spellChecker1 ){
          this.spellChecker1 = spellChecker1;
       }
       public SpellChecker getSpellChecker() {
          return spellChecker1;
       }
       public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
       }
       public String getName() {
          return name;
       }

   public void spellCheck() {
       System.out.println(" TextEditor name is " +name);
      spellChecker1.checkSpelling();
   }
}

public class TextEditorMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

        ApplicationContext context = new 
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml"); 
        TextEditor tEditor = (TextEditor) context.getBean("textEditor");
        tEditor.spellCheck();   
    }
}
```

Spring beans configuration:

```
<bean id = "spellChecker1" class = "com.spring.beans.SpellChecker">
</bean>

<bean id = "textEditor" class = "com.spring.beans.TextEditor" autowire="byName">
   <property name = "name" value = "text1"/>
</bean>
```

When I give `spellChecker1` as bean id it is not working. Below are the console o/p,

```
Inside SpellChecker constructor.
 TextEditor name is text1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.spring.beans.TextEditor.spellCheck(TextEditor.java:26)
    at com.spring.main.TextEditorMain.main(TextEditorMain.java:15)
```

Bean id and reference name both are same `spellChecker1` but still not working. But the strange thing is if I change the bean id in xml from `spellChecker1`  to `spellChecker` the code is working and giving below o/p,

```
Inside SpellChecker constructor.
 TextEditor name is text1
Inside checkSpelling.
```

So why dependency is not added when I am using `spellChecker1` ?

Comment: Because you did not declare a dependency - you just made a setter.

Comment: Because the name of the **field** isn't the same as the name of a **property**. Your property is still named `spellChecker` as property names are defined by the get/set methods of a class not by the name of the fields (and this as nothing to do with Spring but how the Java Bean specification works/is defined). So actually it is working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually works as designed. Your **property** is named `spellChecker` not `spellChecker1`. You have a **field** named `spellChecker1`.

The name of the **field** is not the same as the name of a **property**. A name of the property is defined by the `get` and `set` methods available on a class. As you have a `setSpellChecker` (and the corresponding getter) there is a **property** named `spellChecker`.

All of this is written down in the [JavaBeans Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) (which was written somewhere in 1998!)

> Basically properties are named attributes associated with a bean that can be read or written by calling appropriate methods on the bean. Thus for example, a bean might have a `foreground` property that represents its foreground color. This property might be read by calling a `Color getForeground()` method and updated by calling a `void setForeground(Color c)` method.
>
> *Source the JavaBeans Specification.*

Comment: Thanks Deinum for the clear clarification. I got it now. Previously I had an idea that filed name and property name are same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void setSpellChecker( SpellChecker spellChecker1 ){
        this.spellChecker1 = spellChecker1;
    }
```

Just change setter method name from setSpellChecker to setSpellChecker1 because to set the value it needs the setter method of that property